# \cdots in header of matrix is annoyingly shifted by few pixels, compared to column entries below it

Tags: math-mode, matrices

That's my code:

```
\begin{equation}
  P=
  \begin{blockarray}{*{4}{c} l}
    \begin{block}{*{4}{>{$\normalsize}c<{$}} l}
      \text{Zustand 1} & \text{Zustand 2} &$\cdots$& \text{Zustand K} &\\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{[*{4}{c}]>{$\normalsize}l<{$}}
      0.4 & 0.2 & \cdots & 7 \bigstrut[t]& Zustand 1 \\
      0.15 & 0.5 & \cdots & 7 & Zustand 2 \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
      0.2 & 0.35 & \cdots & 7 &  Zustand K \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\end{equation}
```

And that's how it looks like:
[image]

As you can see there is this tiny shift. I have tried messing with the fontsize and whatnot but couldn't figure it out.

Is there a way to fix it? I guess it has to do with the fact that I have to use mathmode again for \cdots?

Edit: I think it also applies to the outer column headers with \vdots..

Comment: Please extend your code snippet to a complete example which begins with `\documentclass` and contains one `document` environment and the definitions for `blockarray` and `block` envs. Why you input `$\cdots$` when the cell is already in math mode? Plus, specifying font size in math mode, as in`$\normalsize ...$`, is not recommended.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear why you turn on and off math mode. I provide the solution for `blkarray`, but also a simpler one based on `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{blkarray,bigstrut} % first solution

\usepackage{nicematrix} % second solution

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  P=
  \begin{blockarray}{*{4}{c} l}
    \begin{block}{*{4}{c} l}
      \text{Zustand 1} & \text{Zustand 2} &\cdots& \text{Zustand K} &\\
    \end{block}
    \begin{block}{[*{4}{c}]>{$}l<{$}}
      0.4 & 0.2 & \cdots & 7 \bigstrut[t]& Zustand 1 \\
      0.15 & 0.5 & \cdots & 7 & Zustand 2 \\
      \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
      0.2 & 0.35 & \cdots & 7 &  Zustand K \\
    \end{block}
  \end{blockarray}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}
  P=
  \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-col]
  \text{Zustand }1 & \text{Zustand }2 &\cdots& \text{Zustand }K &\\
  0.4 & 0.2 & \cdots & 7 & \text{Zustand }1 \\
  0.15 & 0.5 & \cdots & 7 & \text{Zustand }2 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  0.2 & 0.35 & \cdots & 7 &  \text{Zustand }K \\
  \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As F. Pantigny, the author of `nicematrix`, remarks, you might use `renew-dots` to get

```
\begin{equation}
  P=
  \begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row,last-col,renew-dots]
  \text{Zustand }1 & \text{Zustand }2 &\cdots& \text{Zustand }K &\\
  0.4 & 0.2 & \cdots & 7 & \text{Zustand }1 \\
  0.15 & 0.5 & \cdots & 7 & \text{Zustand }2 \\
  \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
  0.2 & 0.35 & \cdots & 7 &  \text{Zustand }K \\
  \end{bNiceMatrix}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Comment: For the answer with `nicematrix`, you should use `\Cdots`, `\Vdots`, etc. (or use the key `renew-dots`).

Comment: @F.Pantigny I don't really like them, actually.

Comment: Ah ! In that case, of course...

Comment: @F.Pantigny Anyway, I added it.